# Flutter - Redirect to specific screen from Push notification in iOS lock screen

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, deep-linking

I have redirection logic to specific screen by clicking FCM push notification in flutter project.

Here is redirection code in main.dart file.

**main.dart**

```
Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
NotificationModel notification = NotificationModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(payload));
switch (notification.screen) {
  case 'goals':
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DashboardScreen(openGoals: true),
      ),
    );
    break;
  case 'contacts-contactview-insight':
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ContactsProspectScreen(notification.id),
      ),
    );
    break;
  case 'share-article':
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ArticleViewScreen(notification.id),
      ),
    );
    break;
  case 'news-details':
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => NewsViewScreen(notification.id),
      ),
    );
    break;
  default:
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DashboardScreen(),
      ),
    );
    break;
  }
}
```

While running application on iOS, if click push notification it redirect to specific screen.

First time it open specific screen from lock screen, but from second time it doesn't redirect to screen from the lock screen on iOS.

When I test it on android device redirection works well in lock screen.

Comment: Did you have any error in console?

Comment: can you print payload and share the log

Comment: API response is correct and normal